# Qt Build Error: g++-4.2: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently using qt 4.7.4 on Mac OSX 10.7.2 with XCode 4.2 installed and whenever I try to build and run a project I'm getting this error: g++-4.2: No such file or directory. Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: How do you configure your project? Do you set any mkspec explicitly or use the Xcode project generation, or do you just run qmake/use Qt creator? g++-4.2 was there in older Xcode versions, now there is only g++ (which is actually llvm with the gcc frontend). You might also want to try Qt 4.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about OSX, but I had that problem on windows and it might happen that you have whitespace character somewhere in your path (either where you installed qt or where your project is)...